# Run a bash for loop zero times

Tags: bash, for-loop

For a c-style language `for` loop the following executes zero times:

```
for (int myvar = 0; myvar <= -3; myvar++) {
   printf("hi")
}
```

`bash` instead will execute the loop four times by going by -1

```
for j in {0..-3}; do echo 'hi'; done

hi
hi
hi
hi
```

The following will execute once

```
for j in {1..4..0}; do echo 'hi'; done

hi
```

So how to avoid executing the loop short of commenting the entire thing out?  I'd like to control this via variables in the loop indices:

```
first=0
last=-3
step=1
for j in {$first..$last..$step}; do echo 'hi'; done

hi
```

Comment: The first loop you posted will actually produce a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ((j=0; j<=-3; j++)); do
    echo hi
done

for ((j=first; j<=last; j+=step)); do
    echo hi
done
```

Comment: Oh bash *has* the c-style looping (albeit with slightly different syntax)